# Regex - Grouping?

Tags: regex

I could really use some help. I have the following two lines.

```
<TD noWrap>Data: <B><SPAN class="TableBody clsBold">4</SPAN></B></TD>
<TD noWrap>Format: <B><SPAN class="TableBody clsBold">9</SPAN>/<SPAN class=TableBody> </SPAN></B></TD>
```

I need to grab the text between the tags (4 and 9 respectively)

I'm using the following regex statement:

```
(\s)*(<B>)*<(?<SPAN>\w*)(?:.*)>(?:.*)</\k<SPAN>>
```

This works great for the first line as in:

```
Data: (\s)*(<B>)*<(?<SPAN>\w*)(?:.*)>(?:.*)</\k<SPAN>>
```

But doesn't work with

```
Format: (\s)*(<B>)*<(?<SPAN>\w*)(?:.*)>(?:.*)</\k<SPAN>>
```

because it grabs the SPAN after the section I need, so I don't get the 9 in group 4.

How do I get what I need using the same Regex line with different prefix.

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML is usually a bad idea. Have you considered alternatives such as an HTML parser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. That said, what programming language are your driving your regex with? we'll recommend a better option to more reliably parse stuff out from HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would specify exactly what it is I'm looking for in the regex. That being said, something like this should suffice:

```
<TD noWrap>([A-Za-z]+:)\s*<B><SPAN class="TableBody clsBold">(\d+)</SPAN>
```

It only uses two capturing groups, so you should get as matches `("Data", "4")`, and `("Format", "9")`

Comment: ;( There are a thousand prefixes in the file and I only need a few of them! So I toss the few that I need in an array use as prefix to the regex. I get the lines that I need but not the grouping for the second (Format) line.

Comment: Actually, on second thought! This works out, because I can just cycle through all formatted lines. Brilliant! You gotta love SO!

Comment: How would I get this regex from picking up the second set of SPAN Tags: <TD width="20%">Zip Code: <B><SPAN class="TableBody clsBold">06902</SPAN>-<SPAN class="TableBody clsBold"> 2630</SPAN></B></TD></TR>

Comment: Do you need it to capture the value within the second set of span tags, or no?

Comment: No. Don't need second value. But I believe I figured it out.